# Oracle NVL function equivalent in JQPL in EclipseLink (Version 2.1.3)?

Tags: java, oracle, function, eclipselink

I do this JPQL query

```
SELECT e 
  FROM Expediente e 
 WHERE e.fechaBaja is null 
 ORDER BY e.idSituacion ASC, 
          e.idExpediente ASC
```

but when `e.idSituacion` is null, eclipseLink not return this registry.

How could i do this query with oracle function `nvl`? Is  Is EclipseLink 2.1.3 support this function?

```
SELECT  nvl(e.idSituacion,' ')  
  FROM Expediente e 
 WHERE e.fechaBaja is null 
 ORDER BY e.idSituacion ASC, 
          e.idExpediente ASC
```

or

```
SELECT e 
  FROM Expediente e 
 WHERE e.fechaBaja is null 
   and nvl(e.idSituacion,' ') 
 ORDER BY e.idSituacion ASC, 
       e.idExpediente ASC
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It´s a eclipseLink Bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294092.

I need native sql, example http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2011/12/problem-withjpa-join-column-null-values-and-orderby/

Comment: This answer is wrong - it is not a bug. If Expediente.idSituacion is a relational mapping, JPA requires that using e.idSituacion in a query result in an INNER JOIN, which then filters out nulls. As the 'feature' referenced states, if you want nulls included, you need to define the join as a left outer join, and use that in the order by clause.

Answer (score 9):

**COALESCE**

I don't exactly see how it will help you, but you can use `COALESCE` function: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions

(This is similar to`NVL`, but `NVL` is Oracle specific, `COALESCE` is ANSI standard.)

**Order**

With `ORDER BY e.idSituacion ASC` null values will be at the end of the results.

If you want to have your null values first you can use `NULLS FIRST` clause:

`ORDER BY e.idSituacion ASC NULLS FIRST`

(Only from Eclipselink 2.4)

Comment: It´s a eclipseLink Bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294092. I need native sql, example http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2011/12/problem-withjpa-join-column-null-values-and-orderby/

Comment: The post you linked seems to have the solution. Why don't you use it? Is there any problem with that?  How native `nvl` will help?